# Does Solidworks have a command line like Rhino and AutoCAD?

Tags: solidworks

If it does, anyone know how to toggle it on?
If it doesn't, anyone know a good doctor for anger management?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/solidworks/acadhelp/command_line.htm) is the only command line I know of.